# How to send value from controller of Laravel to Vue.js?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have controller "SomethingController", model "ValueModel" and View "Show.blade.php" and vue with component "vue-component"
Now i want to get send value (i got from model "ValueModel" and the value is in JSON format) from **SomethingController** to **Show.balde.php** which will consist vue **"vue-component"**. Finally, I want to get value in vue from the controller.

I know how to send a value from controller to view. And I have sent it to vue when the value is in the string by using **props**. But I am not being able to send JSON value from prop to vue.

**Controller**

```php
//SomethingController.php
class SomethingControllerextends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $e = ValueModel::get();
        $e = json_encode($e->toArray());
        return view('pages.Show')->with('e', $e);
    }
}
```

**View**

```php
//Show.blade.php
<div class="app">
    <vue-component data={!!$e!!}></vue-component>
</div>
```

**Vue**

```js
//SomethingController.php
<script>
export default {
    props: ['data'],
    data(){
        return{
            d : this.data,
        }
    },
    beforeCreate(){
        console.log('helllo');
        console.log(d)
        },
}
</script>
```

To my surprise i am getting data being printed on window. and operations in function beforeCreate() is not working after the value is being printed on window.
[image: ![image of wrong output]
As shown in image, data is being printed on windows that is send from controller where as i want the data in vue.  I also want to know why it is being printed.

> **All works fine for String being returned from controller**

Comment: I think quotes are missing:  data ="{!! $e !!}"

Comment: I tested all kinds of scenarios and no luck reproducing the error. All works fine on my system. Check if the json itself isn't a problem. Try passign a simple array converted to json.

Comment: @PeterMatisko Can you please show me your code.

Comment: I got the answer, here single quote must be used .
data = '{!!$e!!}'. This is so because the data inside $e has double quote. For eg: [{"country":"Alwaysland","zip":"0023"},{"country":"Neverland","zip":"00111"}].
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you resolved that! I tried it with both types of quotes and it still worked. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, here single quote must be used.
`data = '{!!$e!!}'` This is so because the data inside `$e` has **double quote**. For eg: `[{"country":"Alwaysland","zip":"0023"},{"country":"Neverland","zip":"00111"}]`